# Return non-null value from two tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables,  `T1` and `T2` with same set of columns. I need to issue a query which will return me value of columns from either table whichever is not null. If both columns are null return null as the value of that column.

The columns are `c1`,`c2`,c3,cond1.

I issued the following query. The problem is that if one subquery fails the whole query fails. Somebody please help me. Probably there is another simple way.

```
SELECT NVL(T1.c1, T2.c1) c1,NVL(T1.c2, T2.c2) c2,NVL(T1.c3, T2.c3) c3
FROM   (SELECT c1,c2,c3
        FROM   T1
        WHERE  cond1 = 'T10') T1
      ,(SELECT c1,c2,c3
        FROM   T2
        WHERE  cond1 = 'T200') T2 ;
```

Comment: Have you oversimplified your example? Or are you taking one row from T1 and, if it is null, one row from T2? Or are you missing a join condition between your tables?

Comment: This is a real life example. I simply want to get value of T1 table if available. Otherwise return the value from T2 table. This works if both the subquery returns a row. However, if one subquery return 0 row then the whole query returns nothing. But what is required is to return the value from the other subquery. May be I am not doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT NVL((SELECT T1.c1
              FROM T1
             WHERE T1.c2 = 'T10'),
           (SELECT T2.c1
              FROM T2
             WHERE T2.c2 = 'T200')) AS c1
FROM dual
```

Or you may prefer a [full outer join](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php):

> ```
>     SELECT NVL(T1.c1, T2.c1) AS c1
>           FROM T1      FULL OUTER JOIN T2 ON 1=1
>          WHERE T1.c2 = 'T10'
>            AND T2.c2 = 'T200'
> ```

Your result is logical. If the first table is null no combination of values will exist in the [natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).

**EDIT**. After some new requirements we can use a hack to get the row. Lets get all three possibilities, T1, T2 or all nulls and select the first one:

> ```
> SELECT *
>   FROM ( (SELECT T1.*
>             FROM T1
>            WHERE T1.c2 = 'T10')
>       UNION ALL  
>          (SELECT T2.*
>             FROM T2
>            WHERE T2.c2 = 'T200')
>       UNION ALL
>          (SELECT T2.*
>             FROM dual 
>        LEFT JOIN T1 ON 1 = 0 ) )
>   WHERE ROWNUM = 1
> ```

Comment: what if T2 is NULL but not T1? In this case RIGHT JOIN wouldn't return a single record. would it?

Comment: Thank you, Your query is correct. However, my original tables have around 100 columns and I want to return the full row of all these column in a single query like

Comment: Good point borjab! I'm gonna delete my comment so as to not confuse anyone!!

Comment: Then, use the FULL OUTER JOIN syntax. Adapt the ON clause if you want to add a relationship between tables.

I hope this link helps http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: Hi borjab, If T2 is null return value from T1. If both are null return null. If value is available in either of the tables for any of the 100 columns then return that row. This is actual requirement. Thanks for your answers and time.

Comment: borjab, I am very thankful that you are trying to help. I have modified my original question. Actually what I need is a full row with non-null values of either table. Sorry for framing the question wrongly. I used a single column to simplify my question. But that failed to explain my requirement.